# Active Record (Rails) MySQL Secure Connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, security, activerecord

Now, I haven't been able to find any good resources on this subject so I'll ask my question here and see if anyone has any suggestions/recommendations.

I will be deploying a Ruby on Rails application soon (Active Record ORM), and my database (MySQL or PostgreSQL) will be located at an external location (outside of 127.0.0.1 range).

I am able to connect to the external MySQL database, simply by unbinding the address in the `/etc/mysql/my.conf` and adding a user that takes connections from external locations. However, since the data is being transferred from my application server to my MySQL server, how (in)secure is this?

Do I need to do some form of encryption? Does Active Record do anything in the background to protect data from being hijacked (or whatever you call it) during the transfer? Or is my data secure enough by default with MySQL and/or PostgreSQL when working with databases at external locations?

So in short: Is there anything (extra) I **should** be doing when my MySQL or PostgreSQL database is located at an external location, rather than when it's in localhost range?

Any suggestions, pointers, recommendations and resources would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: To better answer this question, can you please share the name/type of hosting vendor you are looking to deploy to?

Comment: Both on Amazon EC2, just different instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It strongly depends on how the application server and the database server are connected.

If the traffic is routed in the wild (i.e. you dont have a virtual private network connecting your servers), you can set up an SSL connection between your Rails app and MySQL:

- MySQL supports secure (encrypted) connections between MySQL clients and the server using the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) protocol. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-connections.html).
- ActiveRecord has options for SSL security (`:sslkey` and others in `database.yml`). [Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html)

Restricting external connection to MySQL from a given IP for a low privileged user still applies.

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely get me started. : )

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "virtual private network". Both my application server as well as my database server will be deployed on separate Amazon EC2 instances. Would you consider this within a "safe" network or do you recommend using SSL in this case?

Answer (score 1):

As well as looking at the option of running over SSL, you can and should lock the database server to only accept connections from specific IP addresses.

I would generally only run SSL if the connection is entirely untrusted as it can have some performance impacts.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'm running this on EC2 so I believe I do not have an IP address to do this, only a public DNS host and I'm pretty sure that's not applicable. Or am I wrong? (Thus I believe the SSL would be valid alternative, the application won't have very high traffic).

Comment: FYI, EC2 and RDS provide configurable access restrictions based around both IP Address:port and Security Groups.